# How to handle string response from facebook api?

Tags: ios, nsstring, fbconnect

Hi, I got the string from facebook api as:

```
family = (
    {relationship = brother;uid = 100767;},
   relationship = cousin;uid = 10900;},
   {name = myaunt;relationship = aunt;},
   { name = krish; relationship = uncle;}
);
```

How to get an array of relationship and uid from this?

I got the result as:

```
relation = (
    brother,
    cousin,
    aunt,
    uncle
)
```

How to handle this string?

Comment: I formatted and find the cousin line is missing {, check once again...

Comment: but  relationship = brother there is missing of double quorts(" ") ie relationship = "brother" as response. so how to handle this

Comment: If you say this is string then its fine, but this is not a valid JSON.

Comment: yes thaths the response from facebook. so how can i handle ?is it possible ?

Comment: check for valid Json here : http://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native code to parse a JSON response with objective-c, but there are third party libraries readily available. [TouchJSON](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON) is a popular example of this.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ios 5

```
NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: self.responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];
```

else use SBJSON from github parser to parse the repsonse of facebook api

```
NSArray *response = [[responseDictionary objectForKey:@"family"] valueForKey:@"relationship"];
```

and store them in array same can be achieved for UID also

Comment: yes that am doing and i got the response is shown in question.ie missing of double quarts in response

Comment: relation = (
    brother,
    cousin,
    aunt,
    uncle
) how to get in array as object at index

Comment: changed answer can you verify this

Comment: yes my question is how to handle this response is there any way to handle the string?